# Delete matching file from every subfolder of current dir

Tags: shell, find, wildcards, rm

I used this one to copy file in every dir:

```
find -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 cp .htaccess
```

Now i need to do reverse one and delete file with matching name from every sub directory of one i am currently in

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your description correctly, you want to remove `.htaccess` from subdirectories of the current directory, but not from their subdirectories. In other words, you want to remove `foo/.htaccess` but not `foo/bar/.htaccess`. Then it's simple:

```
rm */.htaccess
```

You could have done without `find` for your initial command. `find` is mostly useful when you want to traverse a directory recursively, i.e. apply to the subdirectories and subsubdirectories and so on.

```
for d in */; do cp -p .htaccess "$d"; done
```

Comment: Wow! the `*/` is new for me, thanks! BTW I am quite sure the author just want to roll back the initial `find`. Maybe we should ask?

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/dir -name .htaccess -delete
```

Comment: For the current directory, you can say `find . …`

Comment: Yes, but ... oh. I overlooked that statement.  This is more general anyway.

Comment: This traverses the directory recursively, I don't think that was meant (given the `-maxdepth 1` in the question, there's no implied recursivity).

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you previously run the `find -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 cp .htaccess` from the same directory you will run this one:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name .htaccess -exec rm -v {} \;
```

The -v (verbose) option is optional but it helps to see what files are actually deleted.